# Create SQL Server Select/Delete Query from value in other table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, delete-row, dynamicquery

I have a master table named `Master_Table` and the columns and values in the master table are below:

```
|   ID  |   Database | Schema | Table_name  | Common_col | Value_ID |
+-------+------------+--------+-------------+------------+----------+
|   1   | Database_1 | Test1  | Test_Table1 | Test_ID    |  1       |
|   2   | Database_2 | Test2  | Test_Table2 | Test_ID    |  1       | 
|   3   | Database_3 | Test3  | Test_Table3 | Test_ID2   |  2       |
```

I have another `Value_Table` which consist of values that need to be deleted.

```
| Value_ID | Common_col | Value  | 
+----------+------------+--------+
|   1      | Test_ID    | 110    | 
|   1      | Test_ID    | 111    |
|   1      | Test_ID    | 115    |
|   2      | Test_ID2   | 999    |
```

I need to build a query to create a SQL query to delete the value from the table provided in `Master_Table` whose database and schema information is provided in the same row. The column that I need to refer to delete the record is given in `Common_col` column of master table and the value I need to select is in `Value` column of `Value_Table`.

The result of my query should create a query as given below :

> DELETE FROM Database_1.Test1.Test_Table1 WHERE Test_ID=110;
>   or
>
> DELETE FROM Database_1.Test1.Test_Table1 WHERE Test_ID in (110,111,115);

These query should be inside a **loop** so that I can delete all the row from all the database and tables provided in master table.

Comment: Considering that the OP is using 3 part naming, this *infers* SQL Server.

Comment: I am using SQL Server. Removed the mysql tag. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I agree, and why I didn't edit the tags, @DaleK .

Answer (score 0):

Queries don't really create queries.

One way to do what you're saying, which could be useful if this is a one time thing or very occasional thing, is to use SSMS to generate query statements, then copy them to the clipboard, paste them into the window, and execute there.

```
SELECT 'DELETE FROM Database_1.Test1.Test_Table1 WHERE ' 
       + common_col
       + ' = ' 
       + convert(VARCHAR(10),value)
```

This probably isn't what you want; it sounds more like you want to automate cleanup or something.

You can turn this into one big query if you don't mind repeating yourself a little:

```
DELETE T1
  FROM Database_1.Test1.Test_Table1 T1
  INNER JOIN Database_1.Test1.ValueTable VT ON
       (VT.common_col = 'Test_ID' and T1.Test_ID=VT.Value) OR
       (VT.common_col = 'Test_ID2' and T1.Test_ID2=VT.Value)
```

You can also use dynamic SQL combined with the first part ... but I hate dynamic SQL so I'm not going to put it in my answer.

Comment: i can not hard code the column name into the query. Column name will be inserted by client and will change depending on the clients. So i need a dynamic query to generate the delete query.